# What do you call someone who was doing bad things, and he doesn't anymore?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm searching for a meaningful word or expression for someone who does bad things (for example, insulting others, stealing phones...) You would say they are x.

Comment: This is hard to answer as written because we cannot tell whether you want a noun, or an adjective, or a verb, or some sort of multiword phrase, or an idiomatic expression — or any combination of these things.  It would help us answer you if you could please supply several different kinds of example template sentences where you might use this, but leave `___` or **X** or something for the missing part.

Comment: I am searching for the adjective exactly. e.g : Christopher is ____ after he got rich.
Here I mean that Christopher was stealing phones and computers, but now he stopped stealing them.

Comment: I don't see much (only one response so far to my eyes) addressing the last part of the  question ("in the process"). In that case, *a reforming character* (in place of *a reformed character*) could indicate that it's "in process". If the bad behavior was compulsive, you might say 'recovering'.

Comment: Chrisopher is breaking good after he got sick.

Comment: Question body does not match question title. Also, what is the context and what words have you already tried but found wanting? Vote to close.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> - Reformed : changed for the better.
> - Rectified : corrected by removing errors.
> - Rehabilitated : brought back to a good condition.

Look it up on Merriam Webster online.

Comment: *Reformed* is ok, but  
*rectified* doesn’t make sense here. You can’t call somebody a “rectified” criminal — at least, not without expecting a great deal of sniggering. :)

Comment: This answer is not correct. There is no adjective form of rectified that has this meaning, there is only a verb (and it applies to the problem being rectified, not generally to a person) (and @YounesseBagachoul explicitly requested an adjective in comments anyways). You can't have a "rectified" person, or a "rectified" problem for that matter, although you can rectify a problem, and the situation can be rectified (note this is an action not a quality).

Comment: @JasonC It's inherent in the part of speech. [Any participle can be used as an adjective](http://rwc.hunter.cuny.edu/reading-writing/on-line/particip.html). I also point out Google results for one of the phrases you gave "[rectified person](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rectified+person%22)." The other is too often used as a verb in headlines, where the otherwise required articles are often dropped.

Comment: I agree with trlkly that "rectified" is fine as an adjective, but I also agree with tchrist that it's not a correct answer.

Comment: @trlkly "Rectified" as an adjective has very specific meanings; i.e. as applied to electronics (AC that has been converted to DC via a distinct construct called a rectifier) and the (Oxford dictionaries) adjective meaning a purified chemical substance, distilled, e.g. rectified alcohol. Even if you awkwardly stretched it to be an adjective with the meanings discussed here, you would apply it to the problem (rectified criminal behavior) not the thing responsible for the problem (a rectified criminal). So in any case it's usage here is entirely incorrect. You would never use this word here.

Comment: @trlkly Also, 270 Google results of *any* query is evidence against, not for. :) Note that many results are derived from only a few obscure sources (those related to moral theology) not credible as evidence of common or correct usage, and a significant number of results are not actually the phrase, e.g. "... rectified (person ..." or "rectified, person". Note also that the top Google result is my comment here. That was not a particularly good choice of evidence. :)

Comment: @JasonC And I would point out that the comment I responded to did not say anything about *common* usage. It made the erroneous claim that the term simply did not have the meaning given as an adjective. If you wish to say that such usage is uncommon and limited to moral theology, I have no complaints. And I would still argue that, even if there were no usages of the term, the basic mechanics of English grammar would make it valid, if, indeed, extremely uncommon. Ultimately, it sounds as if we don't actually disagree.

Comment: @trlkly That's true. It seems the main point we disagree on is actually whether it, as an adjective, is applicable to the actual person vs. the person's specific problem (I maintain the latter).

Comment: @trlkly It is in no way clear to me that the "claim that the term simply does not have the meaning given as an adjective" is erroneous. The moral theology sources appearing in the search query don't appear to be using the definition given; the only one I see that explains what the phrase means says, "A rectified person was thus one who had engaged in curbing negative emotions (like hatred, fear, and cruelty) and who had toiled hard to create good life habits." Thus the phrase has more to do with negative emotions than bad actions.

Comment: Moreover, you're still making this a grammatical discussion when it was never Jason C's intent to challenge the grammaticality of the phrase "rectified person." The "basic mechanics of English grammar" do indeed make "rectified person" a "valid, if...extremely uncommon" phrase, but they don't specify that it means what this answer claims it means (because grammar and semantics are distinct).

Answer (score 17):

You might say they are [*rehabilitated*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rehabilitate):

> 1b : to restore to good repute :  reestablish the good name of

Comment: Is there anything else you might care to observe or suggest here?  Answers that are not just copypasted from elsewhere are much better than those which are.

Comment: Got a FAQ/meta link to explain that policy in more detail? I had a look around but couldn't spot anything concrete, apart from some general controversy around the single-word-request tag. My general feeling is that the value of the answer is in identifying the specific word, and the "copypasted" stuff is just extra fluff that it would stand without.

Comment: As @tchrist suggested, this is a good start; but you could really improve it by either looking at other words which don't fit so well and explaining it better, or maybe looking at some synonyms and elaborating on them.

Comment: This one is also useful, there is an example in the Merriam Webster : "_The program is intended to rehabilitate criminals._" which means the process of stopping doing bad things.

Comment: @tchrist - I fail to see the problem here. Ganesh copied the definition from an online dictionary. Are you seriously suggesting he should have rewritten that definition merely to paraphrase it? What purpose would that serve, besides giving you an excuse to claim he lacked a credible source? In my opinion, your "recommendation" is utterly ridiculous: Ganesh gave a perfectly good answer that matched the question posed. If you keep insisting that contributors with valid answers must meet your unjustifiable and arbitrary standards, your "achievement" will be to drive them away from the site. -->

Comment: --> The blanket command “Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own" is still arbitrary -- the way *you* are seeking to apply it in this case -- despite the fact that it appears on a StackExchange help page.

Answer (score 13):

Webster online, [reformed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reformed):

> 1
>   :  changed for the better

Comment: Can "Ameliorate: to make sth better"  be applied?

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar No. You ameliorate a situation, not a person.

Answer (score 9):

If you simply wanted to say they were no longer a thief, you could use the prefix *ex-* and call them an *ex-thief*.  That’s probably the most direct and easy way to do it. But that’s a prefix, not an adjective.

For verbs and phrases, you could say that someone has *gone straight* to indicate that they no longer engage in criminal activity, or that they had *cleaned up their act*.

If you wanted to introduce a sense of remorse for previous actions, then you could say that they had *repented* of their ways, or that they were *repentant*, which is indeed an adjective.

With just a touch more religious connotation follow the related words *penitent* (which serves as both an adjective or a noun) and *repenter* (which is just a noun, and seldom heard).

Further out there, you could call them a *recovering* thief the way they do with recovering alcoholics.  That one works as an adjective.

Or if you expected their current state to be temporary only, you might try calling them a *lapsed* thief as has been said of lapsed Catholics, which is also an adjective.

If you were particularly cynical about their current state of non-naughtiness, you might even reach for *non-reoffending* or *pre-recidivist*.  Best not said to their face, though. :)

Comment: For "lapsed", Google gave "no longer valid; expired . . . no longer following the rules and practices of a religion or doctrine; nonpracticing." Merriam Webster's was harder to copy/paste, but they, too, gave no indication of this "temporary" idea that you write about (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lapse). Can you tell us where you're getting that connotation, apart from subjective impressions or personal preference?